# Help with wiring of stereo jack

Tags: wiring, hobbyist

Could someone point me in the right direction. What I'm doing here is I took the insides from a cheap Bluetooth speaker and I would like to rewire it to an headphone jack (male). I have the cable ready and it has a red, white a copper wires (3 of them). That's where I run into trouble. The Bluetooth speaker that I'm using was a 2.1 channel. I'm not sure how to rewire a total of six wires onto only two. My guess is that I could just ignore the bass channel and focus on the L&R. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Top side]

[image: Back side]

Comment: The bass channel is dropped. The audio ground is shared. You now have 3 wires.

Comment: It's going to sound "pants" without bass

Comment: How could I add the bass back?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Taking a close look at the connector, it looks like each of the three speaker drivers is using a bridge configuration -- no common output ground.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe mix bass and treble feeds together using a couple of 22 ohm resistors - you'll need to likely cut down the volume anyway to avoid sonic injury when using headphones and the 2 x 22R resistor will help. You'll need to do both channels. If you can supply the exact pin-out on the bluetooth board I'll scribble over it for you. Without the right details it's guesswork and could definitely be pants\$^1\$ if incorrectly wired. If the outputs are bridged this may be a problem but not a showstopper. It depends on you and your willingness to use small audio transformers or experiment a little bit.

\$^1\$ http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pants

Comment: Wow, I might have bitten more than I can chew. I guess I just didnt choose the right cheap bluetooth speaker to take this from. I've seen it done with other ones and I thought I would be simpler

Comment: @rubito It could be very easy - just a bunch of resistors or it could need transformers and dummy loads And a bunch more resistors. It might even need a quad op-amp and power. Trouble is it's so difficult to tell without getting in there and trying these things. Just try taking the bass channel and the treble outputs on the left channel, connecting them together via 4 22R resistors to make two output lines and seeing if this stage works (leave the right channel stuff until you know you can mix the two left outputs). It might! Then report back!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that J1 (the big black connector at the top, next to the USB connector) is a line-input jack for the speaker. I'm further guessing that when you plug into this connector, it disables the Bluetooth function.

If these assumptions are correct, you should be able to convert J1 into a line-output jack by shorting the adjacent pairs of connections on the back side of the board.

[image: photo]